Excel vba find nested in another find function
I want to use the find function in excel vba and then, when a value is found and some properties are met use another find function to find another value. Somehow the search parameter of the first find variable is reset by the second one and after the .FindNext statment the loop runs forever. Can anyone see the mistake?
Sub findInfind()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cellNew As Range
    Dim datatoFind
    Dim datatoFindNew
    Dim firstAddress As String
    
    datatoFind = 1
    datatoFindNew = 5

    With S_Staebe.Range("Knot_Nr_Ende")
        Set cell = .Find(What:=datatoFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not cell Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = cell.Address
            Do
                'some code...
                ' if ... then ...
                    Set cellNew = .Find(What:=datatoFindNew, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                ' endif
                'some code...
                
                Set cell = .FindNext(cell)
                If cell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop Until cell.Address = firstAddress
        End If
    End With
End Sub

I cant realy find a problem that is related to that.
**edit
Here is an example what i want to achive:
what i want to do old
***edit
new picture
what i want to do

There is no mistake. FindNext is valid for the last find method. You have to apply something to store the last found cell address, and do the next find from that cell in both cases.

No mistake, this is exactly how Excel works - it has only one Find-command with one set of parameters. Using VBA doesn't change that.

The problem is in the algorithm you coded. It starts to work after some modifications:

Option Explicit

Sub findInfind()
  Dim cell As Range, cellNew As Range
  Dim datatoFind, datatoFindNew
  Dim firstAddress$
  datatoFind = 10: datatoFindNew = 8
  With Sheet1.Range("Knot_Nr_Ende")
    Set cell = .Find(What:=datatoFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "Outer", cell.Address
      Set cellNew = .Find(What:=datatoFindNew, After:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
      If Not cellNew Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Inner", cellNew.Address
        firstAddress = cellNew.Address
        Do

            ' payload code here

            Set cellNew = .FindNext(cellNew)
            If cellNew Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Debug.Print "Inner", cellNew.Address
            DoEvents
        Loop Until cellNew.Address = firstAddress
      End If
    End If
  End With
End Sub

It's not so complex to understand what was wrong.
If you need to prevent range overcome, insert another conditional statement:
            If cellNew Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If cellNew.Row < cell.Row Then Exit Do ' additional condition to cancel inner search 
            Debug.Print "Inner", cellNew.Address

It seems for this particular task, recursion calls fit the best
Option Explicit

Sub main()
  findInfind 10, 0
End Sub

Sub findInfind(datatoFind, level As Long)
  Dim cell As Range, datatoFindNew, firstAddress$
  With Sheet1.Range("Knot_Nr_Ende")
    Set cell = .Find(What:=datatoFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print level, datatoFind, cell.Address
      firstAddress = cell.Address
      Do

        ' payload code here
        
        datatoFindNew = "new value to find"
        ' decide here when to stop
        findInfind datatoFindNew , level + 1 ' recursive call

        Set cell = .Find(What:=datatoFind, After:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If cell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        Debug.Print level, datatoFind, cell.Address
        DoEvents
      Loop Until cell.Address = firstAddress
    End If
  End With
End Sub


Thanks for the help but i can't really achieve what i wanted with your code. Let me tell what i want to do in more detail. I want to search all members what are connected to node number 1. But there are some specail members. They have a comment in a different colume. If one special member is found, it has to be replaced by the member what connects to the other node of that special member. After that replacmet member is found, the search has to continue till all members are found that connect to node 1. There can be more special members.
I updated the picture in my question.

I would not like to solve your task behind you. I provided the code which shows you how you should enter the nested search. You need to learn it and apply for your needs. Good luck!

You can mark the answer as accepted if it helps
